# Make VBA produce a percentage, not a decimal

Tags: vba, excel

Here is an example of some code I'm trying to write. Str2 refers to cell B2 in Sheet1 - this is just a plain "10%" formatted as a percentage. However, when I apply the macro it shows as its decimal equivalent. Please can you suggest how I could make it show the percentage - 10%?

```
Sub DecimalAsPercent()

Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String

str1 = "Policy returns "
str2 = Range("Sheet1!B2").Value
str3 = " Per Annum"

Range("B2").Value = str1 & str2 & str3

Range("B2").Characters(Start:=Len(str1) + Len(str2) + 1, Length:=(str3)).Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Resulting in "Policy returns 0.1 **Per Annum**"

I've also tried the following, to no avail.

```
Sub DecimalAsPercent()

Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String

str1 = "Policy returns "
str2 = Range("Sheet1!B2").Value
str3 = " Per Annum"

Range("B2").Value = str1 & str2 & str3

Range("B2").Characters(Start:=Len(str1) + Len(str2) + 1, Length:=(str3)).Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Resulting in "Policy returns true **Per Annum**"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many users here are behind corporate firewalls and can't see images or view imgur. So they, like me, have no idea what you're talking about I'm afraid

Comment: @HarassedDad apologies for that - I've edited the question now so it should hopefully make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the content of cell B2 is `0.1` while `10%` is the *representation*.  To get the represetation into your variable, use `.text` rather than `value`

```
str = sheet1.Range("B2").value  ' will write '0.1 to str
str = sheet1.Range("B2").text   ' will write '10% to str
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you. One further point. I left my code as "str2 = Range("Sheet1!B2").Text" - do you suggest I change it to match yours or would it have no impact either way?

Comment: I really _wouldn't_ go with this solution.  Reduce the column width to 1 and `sheet1.Range("B2").text` returns `#`.  It shows you what the cell is displaying, not what its value is.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks for that piece of info. However, I'm drawing the information from a template and the column width is fixed at 153. Therefore I don't foresee this being an issue.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: Good point, I never recognized that. It's even worse, when you hide the row or column, it's empty...

Answer (score 4):

This will return 10%

```
Sub DecimalAsPercent()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String

    With Sheet1
        str1 = "Policy returns "
        str2 = Format(.Range("B2").Value2, "0%")
        str3 = " Per Annum"

        .Range("B2").Value = str1 & str2 & str3
    End With
End Sub
```